# Calculations on client machine or on the server?

Tags: php, mysql

I will try to make this question as clear as I can but bare in mind that English is not my first language. I have a web application written in PHP using a MySQL database. In a table I might have thousands of entries and in each entry I am storing this data:

```
$hourly_rate,
$minutes
```

when I process my table through a loop, I calculate the net value using the following formula:

```
$net_value = $minutes*($hourly_rate/60);
```

now the question, should I instead add a $net_value field on my table, calculate the net value on the client side using JQUERY and then upload the result of the calculation in the $net_value field? Which one do you think is the best approach considering I might have 1000 users accessing the system at the same time?

Thank you for you help,

Donato

Comment: How important is it that this number is accurate? ANY data you leave up to the client to provide can be faked.

Comment: Classic time vs memory tradeoff. The real question here is are you going to have to do look-ups based on the net value (Example: a specific range)? If you are, then I would store it. If not, then just do the calculation on the fly. (ps. Doing it client side would not be worth it in your case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally I wouldn't store such simple calculated values in the database.  Doing that calculation in PHP takes so little time that it isn't even worth thinking about.

Comment: Alternatively, calculate in your SQL query

Comment: @Mark - true, especially if the only purpose of the loop is just to calculate those values.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how important the value is. If it's accessed all the time and by a lot of people it may be worth storing in the database.

But I don't suggest using jQuery to do the calculation, do it server-side for better security.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good reason to store the calculation in the database.  The good reason is that this calculation may be used in more than one place in the application.

I would recommend that you create a view, something like:

```
 create view vw_rates as
     select t.*, minutes*(hourly_rate/60) as net_value
     from t
```

By putting in a view, everyone will be using the same definition.  So a report that summarizes by region or time, for example, would use the same definition.  In other databases, you can do the same thing using computed columns, but MySQL does not support them.

From a performance perspective, such a simple calculation on such a small amount of data probably does not make a difference.  Do remember, though, that the database can do these types of calculations in parallel if you have multiple threads/processes.